# Exclude something from where clause by using SQLAlchemy core

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following model:

```py
class Vote(BaseModel):

  __tablename__ 'vote'

  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, autoincrement=True, index=True, primary_key=True)
  value = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
  rated_user_id = sa.Column(
      sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='cascade'))
  rating_user_id = sa.Column(
      sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='cascade'))
```

And I just want to make a query with gives me joined data., nevertheless I don't know how to make this query. This is my approach:

```py
query = sa.select(
  [votes, users.alias('u1'), users.alias('u2')],
  use_labels=True
).select_from(votes.join(users.alias('u1'),votes.c.rated_user_id == users.alias('u1').c.id).join(users.alias('u2'), votes.c.rating_user_id == users.alias('u2').c.id))
```

Buy it doesn't work because it includes "user" as "u1" in **FROM** clause.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each invocation of `alias()` produces a unique alias object, even if you give them the same label. Instead give the aliases a name and use the same object in every part of your query:

```
u1 = users.alias('u1')
u2 = users.alias('u2')

query = sa.select([votes, u1, u2], use_labels=True).\
    select_from(votes.
                join(u1, votes.c.rated_user_id == u1.c.id).
                join(u2, votes.c.rating_user_id == u2.c.id))
```